# Load remote scripts with browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, browserify

I really like using [cdnjs](http://cdnjs.com/) to load up javascript on the client-side, it makes my project smaller and cleaner, and loads everything faster as well. I currently use [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) for module loading, which can load from cdnjs and shim traditional scripts to work with it easily. I've been looking more into [browserify](http://browserify.org/) recently as an alternative, and while I did find [browserify-shim](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim), which can shim non-cjs modules much like require does, I'm curious if there is a way to load a script from a remote source with browserify, or if you have to install everything locally no matter what.

If the answer is that you would have to install everything locally through npm, this makes things a little weird. On one hand, you can add `node_modules` to the `.gitignore` file and not have to worry about keeping all the deps on version control if you are using a `package.json`, but on the other hand, you'd need to get the modules back in there on deploy, which means an additional post-deploy step that would run `npm install` and that node would need to be installed wherever you are deploying to, which also seems a little awkward to me for a static site especially.

Really, any ideas or discussion on this would be great : )

Comment: Can [**Browserify-cdnjs**](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/browserify-cdnjs)  help  you ??

Answer (score 2):

The way I think about it is this, you have three options: concat the JS files together locally (browserify) before deployment, load them in real-time (require.js), or a mix of both. To be fair, you can use require.js to concat your files with r.js too. For me at least, I like how browserify is designed to use the same syntax and mentality as npm modules. I think in the end the weirdness your experiencing doesn't really matter. If all the code is packaged together, you deploy, and there aren't any dependencies, seems like a win to me. Also, I think this is more in line with Java and similar compiled languages are doing, which is putting all the deps together in a deployable package. I know I mention Java but don't let that scare you because really we are all benefitting from the ideas of those around us even the languages we think we don't like. If I had to bet my money, I would bet on browserify since it's offering (what I consider) to be a more mature means of handling modules (organized by file based rather than syntax). The npm also gives us a great way to share our code so two thumbs up for them.